# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable(all_line = [line for line in line_list_function()])

Tags: python, wxpython

when I try add function on position "line_list_function" I have error

> "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

```
class LineMultiChoice(wx.CheckListBox):
    """Line choise func for sg card"""
    def __init__(self, parent, line_list_function, chosen_line):
        super(LineMultiChoice, self).__init__(parent)
        all_line = [line for line in line_list_function()]
        chosen_line = [line for line in chosen_line]
        self.SetItems(all_line)
        self.SetCheckedStrings(chosen_line)

    def get_chosen_line(self):
        chosen_lines = []
        for line in self.GetCheckedStrings():
            chosen_lines.append(line)
        return chosen_lines
```

I expect the output some list, and after this, I need to get checked items, but I have an error

Comment: Check what gets passed to `LineMultiChoice(parent, function, list?)` on instantiating. Your `line_list_function` parameter gets passed a list instead of a callable.

Comment: i solved this, i input wrong variable, all_line = [line for line in line_list_function()], but must bee all_line = [line for line in line_list_function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this, i input wrong variable, all_line = [line for line in line_list_function()], but must bee all_line = [line for line in line_list_function]

thanks to all for helping